# Algorithm which allows the backend to find compromised data from a 3rd party service

Tags: algorithms

On my backend I use a 3rd party service which provides currency exchange rates. I use this rate for the funds conversion within the customer’s accounts. As far as this rate affects customers’ money, I have to be sure that it’s legit. Let’s pretend a 3rd party service is experiencing a glitch and returns 100x times bigger rate than it should be, but the backend is going to carry out this transaction, which will lead to huge issues.

The only solution which I found is:

1. to retrieve the same rate from 5 different sources
2. to calculate a standard deviation for them
3. to compare the needed rate with an arithmetic average
4. to compare arithmetic average with a verifying rate

But this algorithm didn’t work for me — a tiny difference between the rates leads to negative results.

Is there an algorithm which can help me be sure that the rate is correct?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like this is not a matter for algorithms, but rather for business rules and risk assessment.

That said, on the algorithmic side, you might be interested in [changepoint detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_detection) as an additional way to detect glitches.